# Checking if scanner input matches strings in an array

Tags: arraylist, java.util.scanner, capitalization

I am writing a program that asks the user their name and how they're feeling. I want to get the program to first, capitalize the first letter of the last name, if entered for 'name'. Second, I want the program to compare the scanner input to the strings contained in the array lists. Currently, if more than one word is entered by the user, then the 'else' output is printed twice or more. How can I get the program to accept more than one word as input' then compare it to the array list contents? I have tried with buffer reader and delimited scanner, but no luck. My code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Conversation {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<List<String>>goodfeeling = new ArrayList<>();
 
     goodfeeling.add(Arrays.asList("never better", "okay", "alright", "not bad", "couldn't be better"));
     List<List<String>> badfeeling = new ArrayList<>();
     badfeeling.add(Arrays.asList("not good", "not good at all", "could be better", "bored"));
     Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in); 
     String response = "", name = "";
     Integer g = 0;
     System.out.println("Welcome to the Conversation app");

     System.out.println("*************************************************************************"); 
     System.out.println("Hello there! May I ask your name?");
     name += userinput.nextLine();
     **String upperCase = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);**
     //Only Capitalizes first letter of first name, but not the first letter of the last name.
     System.out.println("Thank you " + upperCase + ", for providing your name.");

     System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
     System.out.println("So " + upperCase + ", how are you feeling today?");
     response = userinput.nextLine();
   
        while (true) {
           if (goodfeeling.get(g).contains(response)) {
              System.out.println("Nice! I'm happy to hear that!");
           }else if (badfeeling.get(g).contains(response)) {             
              System.out.println("Aww. I'm sorry to hear that.");                  
           }else {**strong text** 
              System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't quite get that, please try again?");
              response = userinput.nextLine();
              continue;
          }
          
      } 
 //If 'not too bad' is entered, for example, then 'Sorry, I didn't quite get that' is printed three times.
 }
```

Comment: What is g in goodfeeling.get(g)?

Comment: The 'g' was supposed to be an Integer, as in 'Int g = 0;'. It looks like it was excluded during my copying and pasting. Adding the Integer 'g' to the if statements was the only way I could get the code to run for the comparisons.

Comment: Please fix your example code. It has many errors, unfinished string literals, missing closing brackets etc.

Comment: "How can I get the program to accept more than one word as input"   You can have the user enter the words separated by white space and split the response string. String[] inputWords= response.split(" "); then you can compare this list with whatever other list.

Comment: I have fixed the code. Now my else statement response only shows once instead of three times. Now the problem I am having is that even if I enter 'couldn't be better' as the input, the program still responds with 'Sorry, I didn't quite get that', instead of accepting the inout and comparing it to the contents of the 'goodfeeling' array. How can I resolve that issue?

Comment: Also, what about the issue concerning capitalalizing the first letter of the last name if entered as the input?

Comment: Update:  I ended up testing the code with the String split as suggested, and the code worked. I then decided to add more values to the goodfeeling array, but only the first 'goodfeeling.add' works and not the additional ones. The only way I was able to get the program to respond with a proper output is to add all values to the initial goodfeeling.add line in my code. I have ended up with a very long line of code, when I actually wanted to break it down to several 'goodfeeling.add' lines of code. How would I go about adding multiple 'goodfeeling.add' lines and get the proper output in response?